# How to find the moment of inertia for a cylindrical segment

Tags: moment-of-inertia

I want to find the moment of inertia for a cylindrical segment, show below:

[image]

On Wolfram MathWorld, I found a formula for the volume of a cylindrical segment. Let

$$h(r,\theta) = h_1 +\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{r}{R}\cos(\theta) \right) (h_2-h_1)$$
Then
$$V =\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{h(r,\theta)}rdzd\theta dr$$

Note, I'm using cylindrical coordinates. My source is here

[https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalSegment.html#:~:text=A%20cylindrical%20segment%2C%20sometimes%20also,known%20as%20a%20cylindrical%20wedge](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalSegment.html#:%7E:text=A%20cylindrical%20segment%2C%20sometimes%20also,known%20as%20a%20cylindrical%20wedge).

(Note they have typo in the order of integration)

However, I've recently been calculating a lot of moments of inertia and I almost always need to integrate $z$ from $-\frac{h}{2}$ to $\frac{h}{2}$. So I'm concerned the limits of integration Mathworld suggests for the volume would not work for the moment of inertia.

I think I can show easily this integral is not correct. If this integral were correct, we could set $h_1 = h_2 = h$. When we do this, $h(r,\theta) = h$. Then the integral becomes

$$\mathbf{I} = \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{h}\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 + z^2 & -xy & -xz\\
-yx & x^2 + z^2 & -yz\\
-zx & -zy & x^2 + y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} r dzd\theta dr$$

If you do this, you get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{12} m \left(4 h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{12} m \left(4 h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m R^2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which does not equal the moment of inertia tensor of a cylinder, which you can find here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

However, if you do

$$\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{h(r,\theta)}{2}}^{\frac{h(r,\theta)}{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 + z^2 & -xy & -xz\\
-yx & x^2 + z^2 & -yz\\
-zx & -zy & x^2 + y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}rdzd\theta dr$$

Then in the simple case of $h_1 = h_2 = h$, you get

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{12} m \left(h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{12} m \left(h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m R^2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which is the correct moment of inertia tensor for a regular cylinder.

However, I'm not sure if this special case is sufficient to show that it works in general for a cylindrical segment. I only showed it is true for a regular cylinder.

Can someone explain intuitively why these limits of integration would be appropriate for the case of the cylindrical segment? I don't really get intuitively how this integral works geometrically to represent the cylindrical segment, so if someone could explain intuitively why it makes sense (or doesn't) that would be great. Then I could be confident conceptually it is right. At the moment, all I'm relying on is this one check of reproducing a regular cylinder's inertia tensor and I have no physics intuition at all.

Comment: You have asked multiple questions related to moment of inertia tensors, and your confusion is usually related to not understanding which point you are calculating the moment of inertia around.

Comment: When you calculate a volume, the origin doesn’t matter.